# Is Multiple Linear Regression appropriate here?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, linear

I'm after some advice.

I have done a log transformation for my DV (this normalises the distribution), which is a continuous variable.

My IV is count data (but it's a 5 year moving average). The IV is strongly skewed to the right.

I have added some control variables to my model.

**I have done some diagnostics, which I want to share with you.**

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Everything looks pretty well, except for the QQ plot---I know it's not perfect, but do you think there's much harm?

What worries me a little more is what I find when I do AvPlots for my model---these are partial regression plots, i.e. they show x and y, having accounted for other variables in the model.

[image]

I would love to see the data points more spread-out. Perhaps I can achieve this by adding more variables to the model. But do you think this looks alright for a MLR? If not, what should I do/use then?

Any justified advice much appreciated.

Comment: Please also include the `summary(model)` output

Comment: I included some summary (didn't include everything, since I used `factor()` for countries and years, so the table would be too long.

Comment: How many countries and years do you have, and what is the purpose of the model ?

Comment: I've got 150 countries; I've got 25 years. I want to see whether more corporate investment to developing countries is associated with larger loans from the Bank (I argue that corporations may be pushing for larger loans there as their subsidiaries could benefit from that). // So far it seems that US corp investment has a negative "effect" on the loans' size. Essentially, if the model is sound, I will interpret this as the US corporations simply investing more in countries that receive smaller loans, as it would be unrealistic to argue that they push for smaller loans. //

Comment: This would align with my interview evidence, where I found that corporations don't influence the Bank's loans' size. // I just want to make sure that my model is sound and I can draw conclusions from it.

Comment: That's quite a lot of countries and years to be fitting fixed effects for. Do you have specific interest in the individial countries, or are you just interested in whether they are developing ? Do you have a country-level variable that specifies the "developing" status of each country ? As for years, do you have specific interest in these ? Basically I'm wondering about fitting random effects.

Comment: Other scholars who have worked with similar data have used fixed effects for years and countries (similar sample sizes). I include fixed effects in order to account for influence on Y due to specificities of certain years or countries (e.g. it could be that during Covid-19 in 2020, larger loans being issued to developing countries because of the crisis; same for 2008); same can be applied to countries---maybe a loan for schools in some island country has to be larger than for some well-connected country, because it is more costly to ship products to the island country for building, etc.

Comment: But to answer your questions no, I am not interested in specific years nor countries. And I don't have a country-level variable for "developing" status of each country (though probably a GDP per capita variable, which I have, does account for that).

Comment: Not having fixed effects makes the QQ plot look a bit better, I think; and it makes data a bit more spread out when I make an AvPlot; and it changes the coefficient (it becomes positive); R square decreases dramatically --- becomes 0.3. If you'd like to see, I can upload these images in an edit. But the thing is that I think there are good conceptual reasons for including in my model, and it's standard practice in the literature.

Comment: Oh I wasn't suggesting to remove them as fixed effects from your model. I was suggesting to model them as random intercepts with somthing like this: `lmer(y ~ fixed_effects + (1|country) + (1|year), data = mydata)`. This will make the model far more parsimoneus.

Comment: Will consider this. Appreciate it.

Comment: You have time series data thus MLR without incorporating possible memory structure in any of the variables AND explicitly ignoring the possible effects of anomalies might be problematic. Take a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166640/combining-linear-regression-and-time-series/166646#166646 for some guidance.

Comment: Why have you deleted most of the content of your question ? This makes the answers that people have provided completely redundant !

Answer (score 2):

I would not be too concerned with those diagnostics plots. In applied work, it is quite rare to get perfect plots.

My main suggestion, as noted in the comments is to remove Country and Year as fixed effects from the model and instead fit random intercepts, with something like

```
lmer(y ~ fixed_effects + (1|country) + (1|year), data = mydata)
```

where this example is using `lmer` from the `lme4` package.

Random effects should achieve the same thing as fixed effects, but in a more parsimoneous way. Of course it will be a good idea to compare the inferences from both models.