# Function that relates two models

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Suppose I have a response variable modeled by a linear model
y1=mt+b
and another response variable modeled by y2=d*exp(ct) i.e. an exponential model. Suppose I have fitted these models separately and have estimated the parameters via maximum likelihood. Finally, suppose I have reason to believe that y1 and y2 are correlated.

How can I find an function relating these variables?

Comment: Why is there a statsmodels tag?

Comment: You need an assumption on the correlation distribution to get a seemingly unrelated regression problem, e.g. Stata has nlsur http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rnlsur.pdf . For a general case the two equations could be linked by copulas.

Comment: @user333700 can these approaches be used even if the regressions have random effects? In other words, what if the correlation is between random effects?

Comment: I don't know of any SUR models that also have random effects nor system of equation models with mixed effects. I guess it will be a difficult problem to separate the various components of the correlation, even more so in a nonlinear setting. But I have no overview over more than the simplest SUR or system of equation models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach for time series data is outlined in [Cross correlation influenced by self auto correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166619/cross-correlation-influenced-by-self-auto-correlation/166627#166627) . Closely follow all the links as they will/might help you understand how to model not only the relationship between the variables but also the impact of historical values while unveiling/exposing unspecificed deterministic structure such as pulses/level shifts/local time trends etc that might be pertinent.